# Winrt component - "WinRT information: Class not registered"

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use winrt component with my c++ game for windows/windowsphone. I have one class and everything was fine, but after adding another class to my winrt component, I'm getting exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x74D02F71 in App1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::ClassNotRegisteredException ^ at memory location 0x0260EA78. HRESULT:0x80040154 Class not registered
>
> WinRT information: Class not registered

What I'm doing wrong? Both classes are in same namespace. Or there are any limitations which I don't know?

Comment: Installed Update 4 to VS2013 recently? Had this problem, too. On a machine without U4 project was running fine.

Comment: @Sascha,yep, I have updated.

Comment: Basic diagnostic is that you forgot to get the component included in the package and compiled your code just from the .winmd file.  Pay attention to the Output window while your project builds, it lists everything it adds to the package.  With the expectation that you see the DLL that you need missing.

Comment: I have found, that VS marks as ActivatableClass only one class in generated AppxManifest.xml. If I add manually other classes - all works fine. But it not sounds as solution.